# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts2-jquery-tags" in jsp

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using `struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1-sources.jar` in Struts 2 I put the jar file in lib directory and I have added it to the buildpath also.

I have make an entry in JSP as

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts2-jquery-tags" %>
```

but it shows an error `Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts2-jquery-tags"`

when I run the application it shows like

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary class:com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery.views.JqueryTagLibrary - bean - jar:file:/D:/eclipse-indigo/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Fundation/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1-sources.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:125
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:208)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:131)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery.views.JqueryTagLibrary
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:147)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:180)
    ... 24 more
```

Any ideas to solve this

**`web.xml`:**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>sampleProject</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30 </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1-sources.jar - is jar containing the source code.

Comment: place struts2-jquery-plugin .jar file in web-inf/lib

Comment: how would i add struts2jquery jar file to my project

Comment: @AleksandrM i included the struts2-jquery-plugin-3.2.1.jar file i clean the project and the jar file to build path still i am getting Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts2-jquery-tags" error in jsp –

Comment: Now you need to redeploy your app so the changes take effect.

Comment: @RomanC still having error javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/getStarted.jsp(4,50) File "/struts2-jquery-tags" not found
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:515)
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:422)

Comment: @RomanC pls check the edited one

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem.

Try

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
```

Instead of

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts2-jquery-tags" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use 
[struts-jquery-plugin.jar](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/list)

instead of struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1-sources.jar as it contains source file

Comment: i included the struts2-jquery-plugin-3.2.1.jar file i clean the project and the jar file to build path still i am getting Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts2-jquery-tags" error in jsp