# Trying to use struts-jquery-tags but run into multiple exceptions?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I am going to use [struts-jquery taglib](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag#Datepicker_with_different_options_and_animations), but the application throws the following errors. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087557/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-struts2-jquery-tags-in-jsp), I changed struts to struts2, and based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772405/struts2-jquery-plugin-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-struts2-views) I added the bean to struts.xml file but to no avail.

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts2-jquery-tags" %>
```

**Exceptions**

```
ERROR [CommonsLogger.java:38] Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Alex/Projects/Myproject/target/Myproject-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:152

Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibraryDirectiveProvider class:com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery.grid.views.JqueryGridTagLibrary - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Alex/Projects/Myproject/target/Myproject-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:152

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts2/views/TagLibraryDirectiveProvider

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibraryDirectiveProvider
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    ... 63 more

SEVERE:   WebModule[]Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:135)

Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Alex/Projects/Myproject/target/Myproject-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:152

Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Alex/Projects/Myproject/target/Myproject-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:152

Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Alex/Projects/Myproject/target/Myproject-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:152

Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Alex/Projects/Myproject/target/Myproject-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:152

Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibraryDirectiveProvider class:com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery.grid.views.JqueryGridTagLibrary - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/Alex/Projects/Myproject/target/Myproject-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:27:152

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts2/views/TagLibraryDirectiveProvider

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibraryDirectiveProvider
```

**POM.xml**

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-dojo-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-grid-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-richtext-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-tree-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-mobile-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
            <dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.20</version>
</dependency>
          <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why are you using the Struts 1.3 taglib?

Answer (score 1):

You have dependency problem:

class TagLibraryDirectiveProvider exists in struts2-core jar, but in newer version (2.3.16) than you declared (2.3.8):
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/TagLibraryDirectiveProvider.html

So simple upgrade the dependency.

Comment: if I change that to 2.3.16.1 which is the latest one, I can not use ServletResponseAware interface anymore

Comment: I posted a question for it as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600204/how-to-have-access-to-servletrequestaware-on-struts2-core-2-3-16-1

Answer (score 0):

I could use the jQuery plugin on Struts2 2.3.14, I just removed the Target directory of the application and used the following dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
             <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
      </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * $Id$
 *
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

package org.apache.struts2.views;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack;

/**
 * Provides Velocity implementation classes for a tag library
 */
public interface TagLibraryDirectiveProvider {

    /**
     * Gets a list of Velocity directive classes for the tag library.  Called once on framework
     * startup when initializing Velocity.
     *
     * @return A list of Velocity directive classes
     */
    public List<Class> getDirectiveClasses();

}
```

And:

```
/*
 * $Id: TagLibrary.java 651946 2008-04-27 13:41:38Z apetrelli $
 *
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

package org.apache.struts2.views;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Provides Freemarker implementation classes for a tag library
 */
public interface TagLibraryModelProvider {

    /**
     * Gets a Java object that contains getters for the tag library's Freemarker models.
     * Called once per Freemarker template processing.
     *
     * @param stack The current value stack
     * @param req The HTTP request
     * @param res The HTTP response
     * @return The Java object containing the Freemarker model getter methods
     */
    Object getModels(ValueStack stack, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res);

}
```

I compiled and added them in my classes folder