# Importing a maven dependency using Struts 2 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, struts2

I'm using eclipse with Maven and I would like to include two struts tags :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sb" uri="/struts-bootstrap-tags" %>
```

The problem is that the compiler says :

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/struts-jquery-tags"
```

The library is correctly downloaded by maven through this declaration:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-bootstrap-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The maven dependencies are in the project's build path.
Why the `struts-jquery-tags` is not imported ?

PS : when I add the `struts-jquery-tags`'s jar manually, I have no errors.

([There is another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087557/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-struts2-jquery-tags-in-jsp) dealing with the same problem but the answers are not relevant in my case).

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is available [`here`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery%22%20AND%20a%3A%22struts2-jquery-plugin%22). You have the problem of downloading/packaging jar file. `struts-jquery-tags` is not imported because the plugin is not available on `classpath`.

If you need additional info you can check docs [Building with Maven](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html).

Comment: The Jar is correctly downloaded with Maven. It's listed in the maven dependencies. The problem is that Eclipse is not able to find the `struts-jquery-tags` URI.

Comment: struts-jquery-tags in the jar if you downloaded it should be there

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your project is **maven enabled**. Right click on your project select **configure** and then **convert to maven project**.

Then make sure you have maven dependencies set correctly.

In the eclipse right click on your project and select **Build Path > Configure build path** ... The select **Libraries** tabs. Make sure you have the **Maven Dependencies** in the list of your libraries. If the it is not there select **Add Liberary** and then **Maven Managed Dependencies**

Comment: As I mentioned above : my project is well configured since all the other libraries are recognized out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be a Eclipse issue.

I guess you've created a Dynamic Web Project and then converted it to a Maven project. When a struts project created in this way there are chances of getting errors which you mentioned.

As long as your project is running smoothly in the deployed server you need not to pay attention towards these.

I suggest to create struts2 project from maven repository. If project created in this way these kind of errors can be avoided.